# VB .Net change forecolor for some items in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, listboxitem

I can set forecolor for listbox items using DrawItem event. However, for example, if my list contains a single red color item, once I add next one with desired green color, I am not able to remain first item with red color. Assuming that I can set color but I need to first get item color. How to get forecolor of a listbox item? Thank you.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem

        e.DrawBackground()

        If e.Index = listBoxSize Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
        Else
            Using br = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, br, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
            End Using
        End If
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()

    End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Alternating colours?

Comment: you are going to need a list or array to track the colors for each item, I think.  For instance, there is nothing there for Red unless the default is Red for the LB itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` class to store the color for the listed items

```
Dim colors As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Color)

Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem

    e.DrawBackground()
    Dim clr As Color = e.ForeColor
    If e.Index = listBoxSize Then
        clr = Colors.Green

    Using br = New SolidBrush(clr)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, br, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
    End Using
    colors.Add(e.Index, clr)

    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

now you can retrive the color by List Index.

```
Dim clr Color = colors(listBox1.SelectedIndex)
```